GoRouter - share custom model between screens with context.go
I have a flutter app for mobile which I am porting to web. So I am using Go Router package and moving from Navigator.of to context.go. Following is a code sample from my app. How can I send all this data with context.go.
P.S I tried using extra object, but when I go front and back multiple times

with browser buttons

my custom object looses type information and is converted to Map<String, dynamic>
          Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => ListenableProvider(
                  create: (_) => GoalDetailViewModel(
                      currentStatus: GoalStatus.open,
                      goalId: model.id,
                      goalTitle: model.details.title,
                      goalUrl: model.details.url,
                      isScreenGoal: model.type.toLowerCase() == 'goal'),
                  child: const GoalDetailScreen())));


If 'extra' object is having issue on Flutter Web, you can use pathParameters, and convert to model in Route class using:
Model.fromJson(state.pathParameters)

